# Space defined by measurable function whose arguments are two measurable functions is measurable

Tags: measure-theory

Let $f, g:\Omega\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $h:\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be measurable.
Show that $H:\Omega\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $\omega\mapsto h(f(\omega),g(\omega))$ is measurable.

We have the measurable spaces:
$(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_1), (\Omega,\mathcal{F}_2),(\Omega,\mathcal{F}_3).$

My argument is about the fact that since $f,g$ are measurable their inverses have to be in $\mathcal{F}_1, \mathcal{F}_2$ respectively. Now I need to show that the inverse of $h$ is somehow in $\mathcal{F}_3$ (?).

I'm looking for a precise proof. Thank you very much!

Comment: Usually, in questions like this, a set $Ω$ carries only a single σ-algebra - are you sure you need to involve three of them?

Comment: You are right, I guess one sigma algebra would be sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, we consider the measurability with respect to *one* $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, which we will denote by $\mathcal{F}$. So we have that $f,g:\Omega\to\mathbb{R}$ are measurable with respect to $\mathcal{F}$.

Now we will prove this by using the fact that the composition of two measurable functions is measurable (which can be proven very easily). So notice first that if we define

$$X(\omega)=(f(\omega),g(\omega))$$

for $\omega\in\Omega$, then we have that $H=h\circ X$. It thus suffices to prove that $X$ is measurable. For this, we show that the preimage of every rectangle $(a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2]$ under $X$ is in $\mathcal{F}$ (which is clearly enough as these rectangles generate the Borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}^2$). But notice that

$$X^{-1}((a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2])=\{\omega\in\Omega : f(\omega)\in(a_1,b_1]\text{ and } g(\omega)\in(a_2,b_2]\}=f^{-1}((a_1,b_1])\cap g^{-1}((a_2,b_2]).$$

Now as $f$ and $g$ are measurable, the above is the intersection of two sets in $\mathcal{F}$, and hence, as $\mathcal{F}$ is closed under finite intersection, $X^{-1}((a_1,b_1]\times(a_2,b_2])\in\mathcal{F}$. It follows that $X$ is measurable, and thus $H$ is measurable.